# Не работает запрос на авторизацию

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, post

Нашел ресурс для тестирования https://reqres.in/
Не получается сделать POST (Login_Successful)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.login-form button').on('click', function() {

    var userName = $('input:text').val();
    var userPassword = $('input:password').val();
    var JSONObj = {
     "email" : userName,
     "password": userPassword
    };
    var data = JSON.stringify(JSONObj);

var getUsers = function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:  'https://reqres.in/api/login',
            type:'POST',
            dataType : 'json',
            data: data,
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            }
        });

    };
        getUsers();
        console.log(getUsers);
});
});
```

Console.log(getUsers) показывает {$.ajax({url:"https://reqres.in/api/login",type:"POST",dataType:"json",data:o,success:function(n){console.log(n)}})}

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не делай JSON.stringify

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.login-form button').on('click', function() {

        var userName = $('input:text').val();
        var userPassword = $('input:password').val();

        var data = {
          email: userName,
          password: userPassword
        };

        var getUsers = function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://reqres.in/api/login',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: data,
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        };
        getUsers();
    });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, все ок.  А почему JSON.stringify мешает?